# There is a white vertical line in Geany editor and I can't make it disappear

Tags: geany

I have this white vertical line in my editor.

Can someone tell me what it is and how to get rid of it?!

[image: Geany editor vertical line]

Answer (score 0):

The white vertical line gives you the ability to collapse the entire code within that function, the if, the each, etc. This is called `folding`. Some find it helpful when they are trying to look through/find code because it hides things they may find to be unnecessary.

[From the Geany documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#folding)

> If you don't like it or don't need it at all, you can simply disable
>   folding support completely in the preferences dialog.
>
> The folding behavior can be changed with the "Fold/Unfold all children
>   of a fold point" option in the preference dialog. If activated, Geany
>   will unfold all nested fold points below the current one if they are
>   already folded (when clicking on a [+] symbol). When clicking on a [-]
>   symbol, Geany will fold all nested fold points below the current one
>   if they are unfolded.
>
> This option can be inverted by pressing the Shift key while clicking
>   on a fold symbol. That means, if the "Fold/Unfold all children of a
>   fold point" option is enabled, pressing Shift will disable it for this
>   click and vice versa.